# How can I limit access to a SVN repository per user?

Tags: svn

i got require from manager on below

1. if user has account on subversion, they can check out or commit to repository
2. some folder or file on repository. user can't commit but user can check-out (read-only)

   > http://server.com/repos/project1/data/install.php
3. some user(ex. admin) can commit to restrict folder/file on above

on below is my config

```
<Location /repos/project1>
  DAV svn
  SVNPath /var/www/svn/repos/project1
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "restrict zone"
  AuthUserFile /var/www/svn/.htpasswd
  AuthGroupFile /var/www/svn/.htgrp
  Require group admin web-dev
</Location>
```

i try to use AuthzSVNAccessFile but i got on below error

> Failed to load the AuthzSVNAccessFile:

please help me

Comment: The downvote you got because your endless simple "please help me" at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [svn-access-mana](http://svn-access-mana.sourceforge.net/), from the looks of it, it looks likes it answering your needs,

> SVN Access Manager is a powerful tool for managing access to
>   subversion repositories. The tool provides user and group management
>   and access rights (read /write) to dedicated paths in a repository as
>   well.